# Error message formatting jqXHR response text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im quite an newby to AJAX/Jquery and have created an error response on my program but i am having the problem with how the errors appear, mainly with the jqXHR.responseText.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         $('.result').show().html('<p><strong>' 
          + textStatus +'</strong></p><div>'+ jqXHR.responseText +' </div>');
}
```

This shows as

```
error 
{"comment":["The comment field is required."]}
```

How would i remove the "" and the brackets from the jqXHR.responseText so it appears as

```
error 
Comment: The comment field is required
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You wouldn't.  That's JSON.  You need to parse it and use it.

Comment: How do i go about doing that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var responseText = '{"comment":["The comment field is required."]}'
//desired result = Comment: The comment field is required.
var responseTextAsAnObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
var errorKey = Object.keys(responseTextAsAnObject)[0];
//errorKey should be "comment"
console.log(errorKey);
var firstErrorMessage = responseTextAsAnObject[errorKey][0];
//firstErrorMessage should be "The comment field is required."
console.log(firstErrorMessage);
//We need to capitalize the errorKey
errorKey = errorKey[0].toUpperCase() + errorKey.slice(1);
console.log(errorKey);
//Now we can construct our desired result
var result = errorKey +': '+ firstErrorMessage;
console.log(result);
```